# Mathematical Function Notation

Tags: math-mode, brackets

How do I get this sort of notation in LaTeX?

[image]

I'm using TeXmaker.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `cases` environment from `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

```
\[f(x)=
 \begin{cases}%
  7      & \text{if $x=0$}\\
  3x^2-2 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you `\[
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  7, &\qquad\text{if $x=0.$} \\
  3x-2, &\qquad\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\]` to have better spacing and the appropriate punctuation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I agree. Now the OP can follow it and improve. Thanks.